# Mysql - Update the timestamp

Tags: mysql, timezone, timezone-offset

My timestamp is 8 hours behind my local time so typically

```
2015-08-24 12:50:07
```

Can I update this to

```
2015-08-24 20:50:07
```

Comment: Are you sure the timestamp is wrong or is it just a timezone which is wrongly set?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use field of `datetime` type instead and obtain the value by function `NOW()`